# Access <a> tag inside onclick function in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick

I have a React code where I put `<a>` tag with onClick function. When I click this component, inside the onClick function I want to get access to the `<a>` tag itself and set it's `href` value. Currently I do it like this:

```
render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
        <a href='#' onClick={ () => this.clicked() } id = { 'btn_id' } />
    )
}

private clicked() {
    const a = document.getElementById("btn_id") as HTMLAnchorElement;

    a.href = "new_link";
}
```

This is working fine, but I don't want to use `getElementById` call to get access to the component. Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `document.getElementById()`. You can access the event targeted element from the `event` object as follows:

```
render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
        <a href='#' onClick={ (e) => this.clicked(e) } id = { 'btn_id' } />
    )
}

private clicked(e) {
    const a = e.target as HTMLAnchorElement;

    a.href = "new_link";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer about that. I have another question, and let me past it here as well. What if I need to access another element inside the `clicked` function. Is refs good way to do it? Or there is some alternatives?

Comment: @MamukaSakhelashvili well, I think it really depends on many things. Using Refs is perfectly fine (sometimes it is the only way to go), but only as a last resort (as stated in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) Refs are a sort of "Escape Hatch"). Feel free to post a new question with your specific case.